# WinApi How to force external window size or zoom out

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to fit an external application to specified size. It used to work unfortunately new version of the external app set minimal width and height bigger than the space we have in our app.

Is there a way to force window width and height? I know about function *MoveWindow* but it sets the minimum width and height of external app and crop it to required size - it looks weird and some buttons are unreachable. I guess that there is no way to break minimal width and height (otherwise it would be unuseful).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveWindow")]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
```

If I can't force the dimensions, is it possible to zoom out the app to fit it to the required space? For example can I use Magnifier.dll for this purpose? If I reduce it to 95% it would fit. I found examples to create screenshots using this library or magnifier glass app but I need just zoom out the external app and the rest should be the same.

Comment: *"the external app set minimal width and height bigger than the space we have in our app"* - Uhm, you aren't re-parenting that external application into your UI, are you? Because, if you do, you have much more drastic error modes to fix.

Comment: Unfortunately we are re-parenting it into our UI.

Comment: [Good luck](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) with that.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only modify the size of the external window through `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos`. And you cannot control the minimum height and width of the application or shrink the application through WinApi.